# Criar um Adapter Genérico

Tags: android, android-adapter

Boa Noite! prezados, estou com uma dúvida , alguém já se deparou com a situação de ter várias listas mas com informações semelhantes? uma simples listagem de informações vinda do serviço? gostaria de saber se é possível criar um Adapter genérico. Agradeço desde já

Comment: Supondo que você tenha uma aplicação, por exemplo de cadastro de clientes e funcionários, que possuem características semelhantes, você quer criar um adapter que sirva para os dois?

Comment: Exatamente  pra uma ou mais activities!

Comment: Acredito que tu consegue fazer isso com herança

Comment: O layout da linha é sempre o mesmo?

Answer (score 2):

Sim é possível.

No entanto terá de escrever um ViewHolder por cada tipo de layout do item, um ViewHolderFactory e o seu Model terá de implementar uma interface.

O ViewHolder é necessário para fazer a ligação do Model com as Views.
O ViewHolderFactory para o adapter construir o ViewHolder que usará.
A interface, que o Model implementa, é usada para indicar, através do parâmetro `viewType` do método `onCreateViewHolder()`, qual o layout a usar para criar o ViewHolder.

Para que isso tudo funcione é necessário criar algumas abstracções:

- Interface *TypeProvider*, a ser implementada pelo Model

  ```
  public interface TypeProvider {
      int type(ViewHolderFactory viewHolderFactory);
  }
  ```
- *GenericViewHolder*, classe abstracta de que cada *ViewHolder* deve herdar.

  ```
  public abstract class GenericViewHolder<T> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
      public GenericViewHolder(View itemView) {
          super(itemView);
      }

      public abstract void bind(T item);
  }
  ```
- Interface *ViewHolderFactory*, cada tipo de *ViewModel* será construído pela correspondente implementação desta classe.

  ```
  public interface ViewHolderFactory {        
      int type();
      GenericViewHolder createViewHolder(View parent);
  }
  ```

São essas abstracções que permitirão o adapter funcionar com qualquer tipo de dados(Model) e ViewHolder.

Implementação do adapter:

```
public class GenericRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GenericViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<TypeProvider> items;
    private ViewHolderFactory viewHolderFactory;

    public GenericRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<TypeProvider> items, ViewHolderFactory viewHolderFactory){

        this.items = items;
        this.viewHolderFactory = viewHolderFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public GenericViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                  .inflate(viewType, parent, false);
        return viewHolderFactory.createViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GenericViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return items.get(position).type(viewHolderFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

}
```

A infraestrutura está feita.

Exemplo de utilização.

- Model, neste exemplo representa uma imagem e o seu nome.

  ```
  public class Model implements TypeProvider {

      private int imageId;
      private String imageName;

      public Model(int imageId, String imageName){
          this.imageId = imageId;
          this.imageName = imageName;
      }

      @Override
      public int type(ViewHolderFactory viewHolderFactory) {
          // Ao delegar para o viewHolderFactory a obtenção do Layout
          // evita-se que o model dependa do framework Android, neste caso da classe R.
          return viewHolderFactory.type();
      }

      public int getImageId() {
          return imageId;
      }

      public String getImageName() {
          return imageName;
      }
  }
  ```
- ViewHolder, segue a implementação clássica: no construtor obtêm-se as referências às views do layout e no método `bind()` atribui-se os valores do model às respectivas views:

  ```
  public class ModelViewHolder extends GenericViewHolder<Model> {

      //A ser usado pelo ViewHolderFactory para, através do model,
      //indicar, no método onCreateViewHolder(), qual o layout a usar
      public static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.item_view;

      private ImageView mImageView;
      private TextView mTextView;

      public ModelViewHolder(View itemView) {
          super(itemView);
          mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
          mTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
      }

      @Override
      public void bind(Model item) {
          mTextView.setText(item.getImageName());
          mImageView.setImageResource(item.getImageId());
      }
  }
  ```
- ViewHolderFactory

  ```
  public class ModelViewHolderFactory implements ViewHolderFactory {
      @Override
      public int type() {
          return ModelViewHolder.LAYOUT;
      }

      @Override
      public GenericViewHolder createViewHolder(View parent) {
          return new ModelViewHolder(parent);
      }
  }
  ```
- Juntado tudo na Activity

  ```
  public class GenericAdapterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
          ArrayList<TypeProvider> items = new ArrayList<>();

          items.add(new Model(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "item1"));
          items.add(new Model(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "item2"));
          items.add(new Model(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "item3"));
          items.add(new Model(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "item4"));
          items.add(new Model(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "item5"));

          recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
          recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

          ModelViewHolderFactory modelViewHolderFactory = new ModelViewHolderFactory();

          GenericRecyclerAdapter adapter = new GenericRecyclerAdapter(items, modelViewHolderFactory);
          recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
      }
  }
  ```

Parece muito trabalho, no entanto é quase tanto como ter de fazer vários Adapters. O trabalho extra é apenas a criação das abstracções, mas elas são criadas apenas uma vez. Os ViewHolder e Model terão de ser sempre criados, qualquer que seja a abordagem.
No entanto, esta "é mais orientada a objecto" do que ter vários Adapters.

Fonte de inspiração:

- [Writing Better Adapters](https://proandroiddev.com/writing-better-adapters-1b09758407d2)

  <sub>*Nota:* O *post* indica um [link](https://github.com/meierjan/BetterAdapters) para uma implementação melhorada que permite, a uma mesma lista, ter itens de diferentes tipos de dados e layouts.</sub>

Comment: Obrigado ramaral! entendi a lógica que foi utilizada! hoje irei testar e te dou um feedback

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção seria criar uma classe Pessoa.java e fazer uma instanciação nas outras classes, por exemplo, Cliente e Funcionario, no caso tu faria um adapter que teria os valores comuns das classes. Exemplo:

Classe pai:

```
public class Pessoa {
    private String nome;

    public Pessoa() {
    }

    public Pessoa(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pessoa{" +
                "nome='" + nome + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Classes filhos:

```
public class Funcionario {
    private double salario;
    private Pessoa p;

    public Funcionario() {
    }

    public Funcionario(double salario, Pessoa p) {
        this.salario = salario;
        this.p = p;
    }

    public double getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }

    public void setSalario(double salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    public Pessoa getP() {
        return p;
    }

    public void setP(Pessoa p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Funcionario{" +
                "salario=" + salario +
                ", p=" + p +
                '}';
    }
}

public class Cliente {
    private int idade;
    private Pessoa p;

    public Cliente() {
    }

    public Cliente(int idade, Pessoa p) {
        this.idade = idade;
        this.p = p;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public Pessoa getP() {
        return p;
    }

    public void setP(Pessoa p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cliente{" +
                "idade=" + idade +
                ", p=" + p +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context contexto;

    private ArrayList<Pessoa> ps;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public TextView tvNome;

    public Adapter(Context contexto, ArrayList<Pessoa> ps) {
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.ps = ps;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexto);
    }

    public void notifyDataChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void adicionar(Pessoa p) {
        ps.add(p);
    }

    public void remover(Pessoa p) {
        ps.remove(p);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ps.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int posicao) {
        return ps.get(posicao);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int posicao) {
        return posicao;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int posicao, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Pessoa p = ps.get(posicao);

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha, null);
        }

        //Instancia os objetos
        tvNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nome);

        tvNome.setText(p.getNome());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Fiz um exemplo extremamente simples apenas para mostrar essa possibilidade, qualquer dúvida, só perguntar

Comment: Valeu mesmo Guilherme! vou implementar e qualquer dúvida te falo!